# Find k in a k-sorted array

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to write a binary-search-like algorithm to find k in a k-sorted array. (It needs to be O(logn))

For example, k here is 3:
`5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4`

Here's my try in Java

```
public static int findk(int[] a) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length-1;

    while(low <= high) {
        if(a[low] <= a[high])
            return low;

        int middle = (low+high)/2;
        if(a[low] > a[middle])
            high = middle-1;
        else
            low = middle+1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works for some inputs but doesn't work for others. It should be really easy but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Even a hint will be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the first element which is smaller than a[0]. So you need to compare against a[0].

```java
public static int findk(int[] a) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length - 1;
    if (a[high] >= a[0]) // special case array completely sorted
        return high + 1;
    while(low < high) {
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        if(a[middle] < a[0])
            high = middle;
        else
            low = middle + 1;
    }    
    return low; // or high
}
```

You will get [0,6] on start, then [0,3], then [2,3] and finally [3,3].

The reason why we don't do `high = middle - 1` is that this way we could end up in the k-values which we don't want.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is embarrasing.. I couldn't figure this out for too long. thanks again

Comment: @Pilpel you're welcome, no problem, it can happen. Thanks for accepting.

Comment: @Pilpel just noticed it will only work if k is smaller than the array length, we need to check at start if a[high] > a[0] and then return high + 1 before executing the while loop.

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to return 0 if the array is already sorted?

Comment: @Pilpel hmm both seems to be correct, depends how you look at it, good obvservation.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand though why we have to check against a[0] everytime, and not against some element related to high/low? I really want to understand the logic here

Comment: @Pilpel the first k elements are >= a[0] and the rest < a[0], so when we get a[middle] < a[0] we know that middle is in the rest of the values, otherwise we are in the first k values. Then we narrow down that interval until low==high which means we are on the first index not in the first k values.